# Execute DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE from another schema

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, parallel-processing

I've written a script to update millions of records, using **DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK**.

I also thought about the Schemaowner passing either to session and to CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID table_owner.

```
ACCEPT Schemaowner CHAR DEFAULT 'MYUSER'
.
.
.
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = &Schemaowner.;
.
.
.
DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID(task_name => c_task_name, 
table_owner => '&&Schemaowner.', 
table_name => 'TMP_DUPLICATED_ABC', 
by_row => TRUE, 
chunk_size => &&p_chunk_size.);
.
.
.
```

My problem/question here:

If I run the script with MYUSER, which is also the default schema and that schema has all the tables -> no problems ✔

If I run it with a different schema eg: SYS or APPDEPLOY (more complex users, more privileges etc.), the DML functions inside the RUN_TASK sql_stmt (update,insert,delete) do **NOTHING** ✘

Before the RUN_TASK I also do some inserts and fetches, and those work great at both cases.

---

I did not find any documentation about this problem. Is there a statement that DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE can only work with one schema?

During execution there are no errors raised, no syntax problems.

Comment: ["Apart from the administrative routines, all the subprograms refer to tasks owned by the current user."](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.html#GUID-34F2D688-E686-4654-AE5D-3D14D6CBCA6F)? It's a bit unclear which user you are running this ass, which user owns the task, and what you actually see when it runs; do you get an error? Have you added any debugging?

Comment: No, I don't get an error, as I mentioned in the description, and haven't debugged yet.

I tried to run the script as SYS, but the tables belongs to MYUSER schema, therefore i altered the session to MYUSER, and did the rest of the script under MYUSER schema.
Unfortunately i can not copy-paste the whole script :(